# GDB command for indexing the members of a structure

Tags: python, gdb

I have my structure with several members and I would like to see them all indexed in order.

```
Struct Ant 
{
   int type; 
   char name[100];
   long long int food;
}
```

Now, when I execute the command in gdb

```
(gdb) ptype struct Ant 
$1 = struct 
{  
   int type; 
   char name[100];
   long long int food;
}
```

I would like to see the output something like

```
{
  0,  int type; 
  1,  char name[100];
  2,  long long int food;
}
```

Is there a way to get the index of each structure field in order in GDB ?

Comment: What's the point of the indexes? How would you use them?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: I would like to output the indexed structure to C file and traverse the structure with the index information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this.  If you need this you can write it yourself in a couple of ways.

One way would be to use the gdb CLI: use `set logging` and friends to dump the `ptype` output to a file, then use `shell` to run some other command on the file to format it the way you like.

Another way would be to use gdb's Python scripting capability to inspect the type and display it how you like.  If you search for the `pahole` command (maybe already on your system, try `locate pahole.py` -- some Linux distros ship this) you can see an example of how this is done.